# In OpenERP, how can I force SQL to run when a module is installed?

Tags: odoo

I have a module built in OpenERP that adds some fields to existing models.

The definition is roughly as follows:

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _name = _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'my_special_id': fields.integer('Special ID', required=False, readonly=True),
    }
    _defaults = {
        'my_special_id': lambda *a: None
    }

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('special_id_uniq', 'UNIQUE (my_special_id)', 'Must be unique.'),
    }

    _sql = """CREATE UNIQUE INDEX special_id_limited_uniq
            ON res_partner (my_special_id)
            WHERE my_special_id != 0
    """
res_partner()
```

My goal is to have a field (special_id_uniq) that:

1. Defaults to NULL
2. Is an integer
3. Is unique, across all values, except for NULL

My first instinct was to create the _sql_constraint definition above, but this caused issues: apparently OpenERP doesn't have nullable integer fields, so 'None' is treated as 0. This breaks the SQL constraint, as now multiple values of 0 must be allowed.

To get around this, I removed the _sql_constraints option on the model and added the _sql code which creates a PostgreSQL partial index. To verify that it works, I ran the SQL myself on PostgreSQL and it acheives my desired effect. However, when I create a new DB via OpenERP and install my custom module, this SQL is not run. That is because the model is not being created:

```
def _auto_init(self, cr, context=None):
    #...
    create = not self._table_exist(cr)
    #...
    #Line 3046 of openerp/osv/orm.py version 6.1 function _auto_init
    if create:
        self._execute_sql(cr)
    #...
```

So, how can I run some custom SQL at the point of module installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a `function` entry in a data xml file of the module.

```
<openerp>
  <data>
    <!-- ... your init data records ...-->
    <function model="res.partner" name="_my_init_mehod"/>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

You can see a working example of this in the standard module `document`:
`document_data.xml`  declares a call to the function `_attach_parent_id` to migrate all attachments to the new DMS structure at the end of the installation.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely seems like the more 'OpenERP-esq' way of doing things.

Comment: If we use multiple <function tags and multiple functions, would they be executed in the sequence specified in the xml file? My hunch tells me yes. That would be handy for stacked upgrades between module versions, wouldn't it? The inside of the function surely still needs to be conditional to prevent multiple executions, but the sequence would come handy.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I might have just answered my own question: override _auto_init.

Edit:

Yes, the following works to run the SQL during install / upgrade:

```
def _auto_init(self, cr, context=None):
    ret = super(res_partner, self)._auto_init(cr, context)
    self._execute_sql(cr)
    return ret
```

Comment: I used this to add a 'CREATE INDEX' statement, which executes both on module init, and on module update. (we wrapped the CREATE INDEX in some fiddly conditional SQL so that it doesn't try to re-create the index if it already exists)